# Passing a list of conditions to a function to be checked

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have an list of *n* conditions, for example

```
cond = [x > 0, x < 10, x == 2]
```

where `x` is any variable I wish to test against those conditions.  I can easily test these conditions if `x` is already defined, but what if I want to pass this set of conditions to another function where `x` has not already been defined?  Is there a way in Python to pass this set of conditions while keeping `x` an anonymous variable?  If not, is there an alternative?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "condition object". What you have there isn't a list of conditions, it's a list literal, and the boolean expressions inside it are evaluated the moment the list literal is instantiated. Maybe you can share your actual use-case?

Comment: `lambda x: [x > 0, x < 10, x == 2]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for an anonymous function or [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)

This could be

```py
cond = [
    lambda x: x > 0,
    lambda x: x < 10,
    lambda x: x == 2,
]
```

```py
>>> [f(5) for f in cond]
[True, True, False]
```

or as [**@John Coleman** suggests in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67066390/passing-a-list-of-conditions-to-a-function-to-be-checked#comment118545906_67066390) you could have them all together

```py
cond = lambda x: all((x > 0, x < 10, x == 2))  # tuple of booleans
```

```py
>>> cond(5)
False
>>> cond(2)
True
```

If it's the same as the example, you could check the last case `== 2`